# Rails, get discount amount from 2 helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have small rails shop and with the following to helpers to work out total price and the discount if one has been applied but I want to work out what the actual discount is to display in the view -

```
  def total_price
    price = 0
    order_products.each do |order_products|
      # add the item price to total
      price += (order_products.price_in_pence * order_products.quantity)
    end
    apply_discount(price)
  end

  def apply_discount(price)
    return price if discount.nil?
    if discount.percentage.present?
      price = price - ((price / 100) * discount.percentage)
    elsif discount.money.present?
      price = price - discount.money
    end
    price < 0 ? 0 : price
  end

  def discount_amount
    I need something here to take the total_price from above 
    before a discount and then the apply_discount and subtract the 2.
  end
```

Comment: `discount_amount` can't work the way the other two helpers are written. You need to untangle `total_price` and `apply_discount`, as one currently invokes the other. You can't get the distinct values.

Comment: You're looking for discounted amount at items/products level or the order level?

Comment: Also, try to avoid: `order_products.each do |order_products|`. instead change the variable in pipe to be different. Something like: `order_products.each do |order_product|`, that way you won't be confused with the operations you're performing inside the block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refactor the price before discount into a private method to reuse:

```
  def total_price    
    apply_discount(price_before_discount)
  end

  def apply_discount(price)
    return price if discount.nil?
    if discount.percentage.present?
      price = price - ((price / 100) * discount.percentage)
    elsif discount.money.present?
      price = price - discount.money
    end
    price < 0 ? 0 : price
  end

  def discount_amount
    price_before_discount - total_price
  end

  private
    def price_before_discount
      @price_before_discount ||= order_products.inject(0) do |sum, order_product|
      # add the item price to total
        sum += (order_product.price_in_pence * order_product.quantity)
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you're getting `discount` from in `apply_discount`, but seems to me as though you want four values available:

- price
- percentage discount
- flat discount
- total

So, maybe something like this?

```
def price
  order_productions.each { |p| p.price * p.quantity }
end

def percent_discount
  1 - (discount.percentage || 0) # ie, 100% [or 0% off] when discount.percentage is nil
end

def flat_discount
  discount.money || 0 # (ie, 0 dollars off)
end

def total
  [(price * percent_discount) - flat_discount, 0].max # to ensure we get a positive value
end
```

(NB: untested)

(You may need to tweak a bit for the case [if it is a case] that a discount has both a percentage and a flat amount on it, or if discount can be nil.)

Comment: Discount is a model with the association has_many :orders, thanks for this. I will try and work using your suggestions. A discount can either be % or money value which is why I have an if statement in the helper. There is validation to only allow 1 though.

Answer (score 1):

I would move the calculation into the `discount_amount` method:

```
def total_price
  order_products.inject(0) do |sum, product|
    sum + (product.price_in_pence * product.quantity)
  end
end

def discount_amount
  return 0 unless discount
  if discount.percentage.present?
    (total_price / 100) * discount.percentage
  elsif discount.money.present?
    discount.money
  end
end

def total_price_after_discount
  total_price - discount_amount
end
```